# The meaning of this definition?

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am confused with the term "sub-algebra". The book says: *if $F$ is a field, and $K$ a subfield, then $F$ is a $K$-algebra. For any set $J\subseteq F$, $K[J]$ is called the $K$-sub-algebra of $F$ generated by $J$.*

I have no intuition what so ever about this object. Can you explain it in rather plane words, and, if possible, give me some examples?

Answer (score 0):

With respect to inclusion $K[J]$ is the smallest subring of $F$ that contains $K$ and $J$: if $R\subseteq F$ is a subring of $F$ such that $K\subseteq R$ and $J\subseteq R$, then $K[J]\subseteq R$.
Concretely $K[J]$ precisely consists of those elements $f\in F$, that can be expressed in the form

$
f=p(j_1,\ldots ,j_n),
$

where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $j_1,\ldots ,j_n\in J$ and $p\in K[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]$.

Examples: $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $F=\mathbb{R}$, $J=\{\sqrt{7}\}$. Then $K[J]=\{q_1+q_2\sqrt{7} : q_1,q_2\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

$K=\mathbb{Q}$, $F=\mathbb{R}$, $J=\{\pi\}$. Then $K[J]=\{q_0+q_1\pi+\ldots +q_n\pi^n  : n\in\mathbb{N},q_1,\ldots ,q_n\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

An algebra over a field $K$ is something that is both a ring, and a $K$ vector space. So for example, $K$ is trivially a $K$ vector space of dimension one, and it is also a ring (since a field is a ring).

Other examples of algebras are polynomial rings over a base field $K$: for example, $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ are both rings, but they are also (infinite dimensional) vector spaces over $K = \mathbb{C}$, and so they are algebras.

Now, in the case described. Given a field extension $K \subset F$, we have a few important facts:

1. $F$ is a $K$ vector space. This is pretty clearly true, or at least not very hard to check.
2. $F$ is also a ring for the reasons described above.

Hence $F$ is a $K$-algebra. Anyhow, as for the question at hand regarding the subalgebra generated by $J$: think by analogy to groups. Given a group $G$ and a set of elements $S = \{g_1, \ldots, g_k\} \subset G$, then we write $\langle S \rangle$ to be the *sub*group of $G$ generated by $S$; this is the collection of all product and inverses of elements in $S$, i.e. the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains $S$.

With this setting here, we have the same idea. Pick a subset $J$ of a $K$-algebra ($F$, in this case), and then you consider the smallest subset of $F$ that is both an algebra, and contains $J$. This is the subalgebra in question.

Comment: Thanks! This is so insightful!